# Use .NET for Web Service and return XML

Tags: .net, xml, web-services

Sorry for asking a very basic question here. I don't even know if I'm asking using the right terms. I am tasked to build a program that can retrieve data from a SQL database and then present the data in XML so that the front-end developer can render it on a website. I was simply told to use .NET and WebService to do this. Can anyone offer some advice on where to start? Especially where can I find examples to look at? Any suggestion is great. Thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow is not your personal research team. Did you google ".net webservice example" ?

Comment: Try gOogLe first... you never know what you will find!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should go google WCF Tutorial and get familiar with what a WCF Webservice is and how to create one.  You don't absolutely have to use WCF, but it's likely your best choice if you're using .NET.  Then you need to create a WCF project and go from there.  Database access is simple - just google for a tutorial on that.  Depending on what kind of data there is to access, you can use a simple Sql client, or use entity framework.

Do your research individually.  Maybe you should start with accessing a DB from a simple console app, and then move to writing a simple WCF service that returns something simple out of a DB, and then take it from there.

*EDIT*
Here's a link to a tutorial on working with a SQL Server DB from a C# application...

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/62133-c-and-databases-part-1-high-level-intro-to-working-with-databases-from-c/

And here's a tutorial on a basic WCF service application for "Hello World"...

http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/create-and-consume-a-wcf-windows-communication-foundation-service.aspx

And here's a tutorial on working with XML using XPath...

http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/using-xpath-with-the-xmldocument-class/

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did google wcf and ado.net. I guess all questions can be self-answered by reading articles from google, more or less. But since there are good and bad articles, I feel it's helpful to ask for experts' opinions and get a jump start. But thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

- [Web Services with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx)
- [SOAP Web Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94043/SOAP-Web-Services-Create-Once-Consume-Everywhere)
- [Asp.net WebService](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/aspnet-web-service-or-creating-and.html)
- [XML Web Services Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996507.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your brief wasn't specific about what kind of service, I'd recommend a WCF service. Go to this [getting started tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms734712.aspx) to get a basic feel for it. It's an MSDN one, but I can look around for other tutorials for you if you'd like.

As for the actual getting the data out and putting it into XML, I'd recommend ADO.NET for that (it's a framework within .NET). This [tutorial on CSharp Station](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet) will hopefully set you off. You'll probably only need the first 4 lessons or so to get what you need.

Once you've got your dataset, you'll want a method along the lines of GetXML as can be seen in [this MSDN dataset to XML tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz.aspx).

That last one can be cut down to...

```
string xmlOutput = myDataset.GetXml();
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if those tutorials aren't much help.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create a web service in .net. I found htis article that explains the basics:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337535/Understanding-the-Basics-of-Web-Service-in-ASP-NET

However, web services are kind of "old tech" and might not be the best if you're looking to transport data for UI rendering. You might want to look at ASP.NET Web API:

http://www.asp.net/web-api

Data output will be either JSON, or XML depending on the "Accept" header in the request

Comment: Thanks Floremin! I know I should google.... but is there a one sentence reason why asp.net is better for UI rendering?

Comment: Consuming a web service is a bit more involved and most likely would have to be done on the server. Every time, you change a structure/definition of the data, you would have to "reconfigure" the code that consumes it. ASP.NET Web API returns pure XML, or JSON which you can use directly, even on the client side. If you change the data structure, there is nothing to reconfigure, you can just start using the new data.